# Could not find property 'eclipse' on root project 'admob'

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, robovm

My build.gradle file

```
ext {
    mainClassName = "org.robovm.bindings.admob.sample.Sample"
}

eclipse.project {
    name = "admob-ios"
    natures 'org.robovm.eclipse.RoboVMNature'
}
```

When I try to import this project (https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings/tree/master/admob) into eclipse (when i click build model)

I get this

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * Where:
    Build file '/Users/Vlad/Downloads/folder/admob/build.gradle' line: 5

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating root project 'admob'.
    > Could not find property 'eclipse' on root project 'admob'.
```

What can I do?

Comment: I think `apply plugin: 'eclipse'` is missing from the `build.gradle` file which is why the `eclipse` property is not present for the project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply some plugins. For the `eclipse` task the plugin `eclipse` is required. Apply it by adding `apply plugin: 'eclipse'` to the head of your `build.gradle`. 
Futhermore you need a `java` or other plugin to get the `eclipse` plugin working properly.

Furthermore I see a `mainClassName` defined as extra property. Do you instead intend to start the application from command line using `gradle run`? If yes, additionally apply the `applicaton plugin` by adding `apply plugin:'application'` (see also http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html). This also includes adding the `java` plugin. If you intended to just have a global variable called `mainClassName` you need to apply the `java` plugin yourself (for a working `eclipse` plugin).